# Namespace keyword in TypeScript

Tags: c#, namespaces, typescript, keyword

Trying to find out what does `namespace` keyword mean in TypeScript?

Here's some reshuffle they've done recently to use `namespace` instead of `module`:

https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/commit/224e7630ea17c4547e97f85634f446b877955a67

In the absence of namespace spec, it looks like a rather pointless rename to make the language look C#-like.

Or is there an obscure little difference between the two? The word `namespace` sorta implies the shared scope/space between multiple declarations using the same name. Is that a correct intuition?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can read about it in the [`namespace` keyword](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/2159) issue, but the basic idea is to differentiate between internal (`namespace`) and external (`module`) modules.

> To better align with ES6 modules as suggested in [#2159](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/2159), this PR
>   introduces a new namespace keyword as the preferred way to declare
>   what was formerly known as "internal modules". Our terminology changes
>   as follows:
>
> - **Internal module** becomes **Namespace**.
> - **External module** becomes **Module**.
>
> For backwards compatibility, namespaces can still be declared in the old way (using the module keyword) and no existing code is broken by this change. We may consider introducing a compiler option that disallows using the `module` keyword to declare namespaces.
>
> [Source](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/2923#issue-71149919)

Comment: Apparently so! Nice of you to piece all the clues together.